# Why am I not getting 'Warning'-s included in my Route from the Bing Maps API

Tags: bing-maps

The Bing Maps API can include 'Warning' information as part of each ItineraryItem - things like TrafficFlow, UnPavedRoad, and so forth.

However, these warnings don't make it as part of the returned route.

To recreate:
In the REST Service Toolkit Test app, change the route waypoint(s) in the RouteBtn_Clicked routine to reflect a route that will have a Warning included.  (Test by routing it on maps.bing.com - things like crossing a state boundary, traffic congestion, unpaved road, etc.).  Note that there are no Warning-s in the returned Route.  However, if you paste the raw REST call in your browser, you will see the warning information included in the raw output.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's an error in the JSON Contract provided by Microsoft.

If you change (in the RestServiceModels.cs):

```
    [DataMember(Name = "warning", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Warning[] Warning { get; set; }
```

To (note the s at the end of the Name)

```
    [DataMember(Name = "warnings", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Warning[] Warning { get; set; }
```

Then it all works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for logging the issue on the project. Have updated this locally and will push out an update in a few weeks (have a few other things I'm working on for that project at the moment).